# Getting errors in podfile

Tags: ios

I install `SCLAlertView` by using podfile.

I'm getting 300 errors on `SCLAlertView.swift` file.

I'm using `Xcode 7`.

How to resolve the problem.

Here is my podfile

```
platform :ios, '8.0'

target `SCLAlertView2` do
pod `SCLAlertView`

end

target `IceCreamShopTests` do

end
```

it generate podfile of `SCLAlertView.swift` but getting 300 error.

Xcode be it is latest version not work on xcode 7)

Comment: These back-ticks are suspicious. A Podfile is a Ruby file and back-ticks in Ruby are used to run shell commands.

Answer (score 1):

**First**

If you check in Branch you can find the swift 2.3 supported version of `SCLAlertView`
https://github.com/vikmeup/SCLAlertView-Swift/tree/swift-2.3

[image]

You can directly use instead of installing cocoapods.

**Second**

If you check `SCLAlertView.podspec` you can find the version of cocoapods then you can install that via pods by

```
 pod 'SCLAlertView', '~> 0.6'
```

If you want to support xcode 7.3 and swift 2.3 other wise if you use swift 3+ then use

```
pod 'SCLAlertView', '~> 0.7'
```

Hope that information get your issue fixed.